# How do you attach an event handler to a nested custom user control? VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, gridview, user-controls

Here's my situation. I have a gridview (gridview1) with a custom user control (UC1) nested in each row. The custom user control has a custom public event called "TaskChanged" that gets raised when a button is clicked. On the parent page(default.aspx), I'm trying to access the user control to attach the event handler to but I'm unsuccessful. Here's how I'm trying to do it.

On the parent page:

```
 Protected Sub GridViewTasks_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridViewTasks.RowDataBound
 If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        'Get the User Control
        Dim Uc As UserControl = e.Row.FindControl("TaskResourceAssignment")
        'Attatch event handler
        AddHandler Uc.TaskChanged, AddressOf Uc_OnTaskChanged


    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that on this line:

```
AddHandler Uc.TaskChanged, AddressOf Uc_OnTaskChanged
```

It can't find the control's "TaskChanged" Event (Uc.TaskChanged gets the squiggly lines under it), and running the page just throws an error. I remember a friend being able to do this but he cast his user control as an object and was able to access it. I've tried that with no luck.

The custom control is raising an event and not bubbling an event. I can get it to work by bubbling the event, but I would really like to do it by attaching the event handler to the control. Help anyone??

Comment: Is the event marked with `Friend` or `Public`? So it can be accessible here.

Comment: Its marked with Public:

Comment: Public Event TaskChanged As System.EventHandler

Comment: Try casting the type - Dim Uc As UserControl = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("TaskResourceAssignment"), UserControl)...

Comment: The type must be the exact name of the User Control.

Comment: I just read the last comment and realize this is actually the correct answer. Thanks DonA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast user control to the specific one explicitly, because regular `UserControl` doesn't have `TaskChanged` event.

Something like this -

```
Dim Uc = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("TaskResourceAssignment"), 
   TaskResourceAssignment)
```

Comment: Thanks Win, this was the solution to my problem. Once I changed the type name to the class name, everything worked. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that UserControl doesn't have a TaskChanged event. Neither does the type Control, which FindControl returns.

Your friend cast the Control into a specific control to be able to attach the correct event.

In this case, I believe you're looking for the ITaskService.OnTaskChanged event. So I would try this:

```
Protected Sub GridViewTasks_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridViewTasks.RowDataBound
 If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        'Get the User Control
        Dim Uc As UserControl = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("TaskResourceAssignment"), ITaskService)
        'Attatch event handler
        AddHandler Uc.OnTaskChanged, AddressOf Uc_OnTaskChanged


    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks jtseng, but I was wanting to raise a custom event and not necessarily an existing one. By changing the cast type to the class name, i was able to find the control's events.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `Trycast` for this type of work. Replace `MyUserControl` with the name of your UserControl.

```
Protected Sub GridViewTasks_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridViewTasks.RowDataBound
  If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    'Get the User Control
    Dim Uc As MyUserControl = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("TaskResourceAssignment"), ITaskService)
    If Not Uc Is Nothing Then
      AddHandler Uc.OnTaskChanged, AddressOf Uc_OnTaskChanged
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```